# Associate loaded JSON files with a name for later access

Tags: three.js

I would like to load multiple JSON files and control the visibility of their meshes. To achieve this, I associated them with their JSON file names. I got it working, but the solutions doesn't please me.

I modified the THREE.JSONLoader and passed a new parameter to the callback function. So with every new release of three.js, I would have to patch the three.js file again.

Here is my working solution (client side). See the new third parameter of loader.load(filename, callback, meshname).

Is there a better solution, which doesn't need a patched three.js library?

Thanks

```
// Load the JSON files
var meshes = new Object();
var jsonFileNames = ['assembly/part1.json', 'assembly/part2.json', 'assembly/part3.json'];
for(var i = 0; i < jsonFileNames.length; i++){
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var meshName = jsonFileNames[i].split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
    loader.load(jsonFileNames[i], function(geometry, meshName){
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors}));
        mesh.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
        mesh.doubleSided = true;
        scene.add(mesh);
        meshes[meshName] = mesh;
    }, meshName);
}

// ....

// Access their meshes
meshes[meshName].visible = true;
```

Comment: You could do a pull request to receive a list of files (and not just one) by THREE.Loader. Why do you need a third parameter? you could do something like mesh.name = meshName in your callback. Another improvement to your code: you don't need to create a new loader on each iteration of your for. You just have to create it once.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a callback factory like below. It will work around [the problem with closures when created inside loops.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

```
function makeHandler(meshName) {
    return function(geometry) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors}));
        mesh.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
        mesh.doubleSided = true;
        scene.add(mesh);
        meshes[meshName] = mesh;
    };
}

// Load the JSON files
var meshes = new Object();
var jsonFileNames = ['assembly/part1.json', 'assembly/part2.json', 'assembly/part3.json'];
for(var i = 0; i < jsonFileNames.length; i++){
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var meshName = jsonFileNames[i].split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
    loader.load(jsonFileNames[i], makeHandler(meshName));
}

// ....

// Access their meshes
meshes[meshName].visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Tapio's great answer.  This variant avoids the need to create and manage the `meshes` object. It does this by creating each new mesh object with the desired object name directly in the made handler function.  As before the desired name `meshName` for each mesh is defined by the user and passed to the  handler.  But then the new mesh is created with the desired name by using the javascript `eval` function.

```
function makeHandler(meshName) {
    return function(geometry) {
        material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors})
        eval (meshName + "= new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);" );  //***NEW ***
        eval ( "var mesh = " + meshName +";" ); //*** NEW ***
        mesh.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
        mesh.doubleSided = true;
        scene.add(mesh);
        //*** NOT REQUIRED *** meshes[meshName] = mesh;
    };
}

// Load the JSON files
var meshes = new Object();
var jsonFileNames = ['assembly/part1.json', 'assembly/part2.json', 'assembly/part3.json'];
for(var i = 0; i < jsonFileNames.length; i++){
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var meshName = jsonFileNames[i].split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
    loader.load(jsonFileNames[i], makeHandler(meshName));
}

// ....
```

The various meshes can subsequently (when loading is completed) be referenced by their object names:-

```
// Access the meshes
    //*** OLD *** meshes["part1"].visible = true;
    //*** OLD *** meshes["part2"].visible = true;
    //*** OLD *** meshes["part3"].visible = true;
    part1.visible = true;//*** NEW ***
    part2.visible = true;//*** NEW ***
    part3.visible = true;//*** NEW ***
```